# Is it possible to send a growl message to another user on the same computer on OSX?

Tags: macos, growl

My app currently uses growl to send the occasional message to the user, which works great when I am developing it.  But once it is run as a in production, as a system-level Launch Daemon under a different user, the growl messages no longer appear.

So, the question: **Is it possible to send a growl message to another user on the same computer on OSX?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can send the message via the network (http://growl.info/documentation/developer/protocol.php) to localhost/127.0.0.1. But i can't find a hint in the docs to target a special user.